# autoreconf failed when compiling fribidi

Tags: compilation, autoconf, automake

The command I used to compile was

```
./bootstrap
```

the results were:

```
Usable autoreconf found, running    
main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at 
/usr/local/bin/aclocal line 617.
aclocal: couldn't open directory `m4': No such file or directory
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

by tracing bootsrap, I found that those errors were caused by:

```
autoreconf     --force --install
```

autoreconf version was:

```
autoreconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem.

Comment: the [latest fribidi release](https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi) lacks a `bootstrap` command, so which version are you trying to build?

Comment: also, it is `aclocal` that fails (`autoreconf` is invoking `aclocal`): so what is your version of `aclocal`?

Comment: @umläute, you were right, the problem was caused by aclocal version, I have fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is raised by `aclocal` (which is invoked by `autoreconf`).

Recent versions of `aclocal` should handle that gracefully, so check your aclocal-version (OR: whether you are actually running the correct `aclocal`-binary)

Alternatively, you could simply create an (empty) `m4/` directory in your build-dir.

Arguably this (ensuring the existance of the `m4/` directory), should be handled by the `bootstrap` script, however:

- [current `fribidi`](https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi) has dropped autotools in favor of `meson` (although it still supports `autotools`)
- `fribidi` has come with a non-empty `m4` directory for quite some time now.
- afaict, the last version of `fribidi` that used `autotools` and lacked an `m4/` directory was `0.19.7` (released about 2015-08)

So: please use the latest and greatest (stable) version of any library. If you cannot, you should clearly state that in your problem description, and note which version you are trying to compile.